# Origin and use of "echar de menos"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, etimología, modismos, sinónimos

I've always found peculiar that the phrase *echar de menos* is synonymous of the verb *extrañar*. For example:

> Te echaré de menos.

is equivalent to:

> Te extrañaré.

Based on TV, its use is most common is Mexico and Spain, nevertheless appears sporadically in dialects from other countries.

- What is the etymology of *echar de menos*?
- In which dialects is *echar de menos* commonly used?

---

Siempre me ha parecido peculiar la frase *echar de menos* como sinónimo del verbo *extrañar*. Por ejemplo:

> Te echaré de menos.

es equivalente a:

> Te extrañaré.

Basado en la televisión, su uso parece ser más común en México y España, sin embargo aparece esporádicamente en dialectos de otros países.

- ¿Cuál es la etimología de *echar de menos*?
- ¿En cuáles dialectos es común el uso de *echar de menos*?

Comment: This is a perfect example of a question where "word choice" would be a poor tag because it's about choosing between a word on one hand and an idiomatic phrase on the other.

Comment: La expresión "echar de menos" no se usa en portugués brasileño. En Brasil, en el mismo sentido, se usan frases como _"sentir falta de"_ y/o _"sentir saudade de"_. --- A expressão "echar de menos" não é usada no Português Brasileiro. No Brasil, no mesmo sentido, usam-se frases como "sentir falta de" e/ou "sentir saudades de".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La frase *echar de menos* proviene del portugués *achar menos* (hallar menos) según [la RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=echar).

Rescato algunas oraciones de [esta página](http://hispanismo.org/portugal/9162-influencias-portuguesas-en-el-castellano.html) que reafirman la versión de la RAE:

> «Achar menos» en Portugal y «hallar menos» en Castilla coexistieron para indicar la falta de algo o alguien anteriormente dado.
>
> Pero ya a partir del XVI aparece un «echar menos», con castellanización o erróneo entendimiento del portugués «achar».
>
> En el siglo XVIII, este «echar menos» se convierte en «echar de menos».

Según el [diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=echar%28se%29), *echar menos* (sin el "de") está en desuso.

Por lo menos en Chile *echar de menos* es bastante común.

Answer (score 9):

Es una expresión que nos viene de la expresión portuguesa *achar menos*, cuyo primer elemento tiene el mismo origen etimológico de nuestro *hallar*. *Achar menos* inidicaba la falta de algo o alguien. La forma castellana *hallar menos* se documenta a partir del siglo XIII y subsiste hasta comienzos del XVII. A partir del siglo XVI aparece un *echar menos*, por castellanización o erróneo entendimiento del portugués *achar*. En el siglo XVIII, *echar menos* se convierte en *echar de menos*, con un *de* que Corominas, atribuye a influjo de construcciones como *echar de ver*, *echar una libra de más*.

El texto está tomado casi literalemte del excelente artículo [Influencias portuguesas en el castellano](http://hispanismo.org/portugal/9162-influencias-portuguesas-en-el-castellano.html).

La expresión *echar de menos* es más utilizada en España, aunque se entiende en todo el ámbito hispanoparlante; en Latino América es más común usar *extrañar*.

Comment: +1 por encontrar la pagina con la respuesta un minuto antes que dusan :)